# Role Authentication and Authorization MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, roles

Im very new to Visual C# MVC5 .NET version 2.0. I have created a web application and have updated and migrated the register page as to my own requirements. The next step I am trying to complete is implementing two user roles - "User" and "Admin" which will redirect upon Login to their corresponding page. What steps should I take? I have tried multiple tutorials and am having no luck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "tried multiple tutorials and having no luck"? I see no evidence of that. You should try one of the tutorials and if you get stuck on it, then create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Right now I think your question is to broad for SO - please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try asking on a forum (mabye [Quora](http://www.quora.com)?) to discuss generalities, and when you have a more specific problem you are more then welcome to return to SO with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean you are using Identity 2.0? If so, check this out:

http://blog.falafel.com/check-user-exists-role-asp-net-identity-2-0/

Here you can see they are using method User.IsInRole and then some code... you can redirect to some other Controller/Action